# Delete unordered lists from main list

Tags: c++, sorting

> I have a list: `4, 5, 6, 3, 1, 2`

I have to **DELETE** **number 3**, because it goes in unordered way.That's why I have:

> The first list: 4, 5, 6
>
> The second one: 1 , 2

**In result I should get:**

> 4, 5, 6, 1, 2

*Or another example:*

> I have: `1,2,`**2,2** `,2,3,`**2,5**
>
> Need to delete `2,2,2,5`. Because they are in unordered way.
>
> Result: 1,2,2,3

Unfortunately, tried to find a sort function, which sorts my list , but can't guess how I go for comparison my numbers in the right way. Can you give me a hint,an example or some explanation, please, for the right comparison.

My function for sorrting

E.X. I have inputted :`4, 5, 6, 3, 1, 2`
Got: `1,2,3,4,5,6`

```
struct list * Ssort(struct list *root)
{
    struct list *new_root = NULL;

    while (root != NULL)
    {
        struct list *node = root;
        root = root->next;

        if (new_root == NULL || node->data < new_root->data)
        {
            node->next = new_root;
            new_root = node;
        }
        else
        {
            struct list *current = new_root;
            while (current->next != NULL && !(node->data < current->next->data))
            {
                current = current->next;
            }

            node->next = current->next;
            current->next = node;
        }
    }

    return new_root;
}
```

Comment: This might be better suited for [Computer Science SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You don't have to sort, you have to go over the list and do actions based on how the entry behaves to the previous entry or the next entry.  Good luck.

Comment: For the first example, you could split it if   value on i is smaller than value on i+1 ... and then remove all ranges with only one value. after all you canput it together.

Comment: @stefaanv       thank you for a hint.I will try.